# How to associate Models inside the respective schema using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I am creating a multi-tenant web application using NodeJS, Sequelize & PostgreSQL. I am implementing a shared database, separate schemas approach.

I have a Register Model and a Store model

```
// Register Model
const Register = sequelize.define('register', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: uuidv4(),
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    isOpen: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    archivedStatus: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    archivedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
});
```

```
// Store Model
const Store = sequelize.define('store', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: uuidv4(),
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    tin: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    type: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM('POS', 'WAREHOUSE'),
        defaultValue: 'POS',
    },
    phone: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    archivedStatus: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    archivedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
});
```

The association between them is

```
Register.belongsTo(Store);
Store.hasMany(Register);
```

On tenant signup, I am creating a schema with the subdomain and then syncing all the models to the schema.

```
await sequelize.createSchema(subdomain);
await register.schema(subdomain).sync(); // Register Model
await store.schema(subdomain).sync(); // Store Model
```

It should generate the "registers" and "stores" table inside the schema where "storeId" of `subdomain`.`registers` should be the primary key of `subdomain`.`stores`.

However, when the tables are created inside the schema, the storeId on `subdomain`.`registers` is the primary key of `public`.`stores`.

This is happening for all other associations. I have tried searching it on Sequelize docs, read multiple issues on Sequelize but I wasn't able to find any solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.